# Reporting table needs to get refreshed without killing user's read connection to it, any ideas?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, replication, sql-server-2016

I'm investigating a solution that will allow a reporting table to be refreshed that can potentially have users reading from it at a time that it needs to be refreshed. Has anyone implemented a way of doing something like this without needing to kill the user's connection to that table at the time of refresh?

Comment: Database replication, availability groups, or ETL jobs.

Comment: How is you data refreshed ? (Update/insert/Delete, backup restore, etc)

Answer (score 6):

Sure.  The simplest thing is to just make sure the reporting users using Row Versioning, either in SNAPSHOT ISOLATION, or by setting the database to READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT.  See eg, [Snapshot Isolation in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server).

Then just make your updates in a transaction.  Reporting users will not be blocked, and will continue to see the "old" version of every row you change until you commit your transaction.

If the changes take a long time, you can alternatively build new tables, and once they are done start a transaction where you drop and rename the tables, or perform ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH to switch the table data out to a staging table, and switch the new data into the target table.